# Spring MVC keep selected value in select tag

Tags: spring, jsp, select

I have 2 select tags in my jsp:

First one:

```
<select name="performers">
    <option value="all" label="All performers">All performers</option>
    <c:forEach var="list" items="${list}">
        <option value="${list}">${list}</option>
    </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

Second one:

```
<select name="period">
    <option value="0"> </option>
    <option value="1">Last Qtr</option>
    <option value="2">Last Month</option>
    <option value="3">Last Calendar Year</option>
    <option value="4">Current Year to Date</option>
    <option value="5">Current Qtr to Date</option>
    <option value="6">Current Month do Date</option>
</select>
```

How can I keep the selected value of this combobox from the controller after the page reloads (post method)?

Comment: What about keeping the values in `session` or Spring model ?

Comment: How can I do this? I don't know how to do it with model.addAtribute for example.

Comment: Use a form model and springs form tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

M. Deinum pointed correctly. Use form model and spring form tags.
Assuming your form to contain fields as:

```
    public class YourForm{
        //Assuming thedatatype of performersList as String
        List<String> performersList;
        String performers;
        ...
        //setters and getters
    }
```

In your controller method which delegates to the jsp:

```
    ...
    YourForm form = new YourForm();
    //set your performersList in form 
    //set  performers in form - the selected value to be displayed in view
    model.addAttribute("yourForm", form):
    ...
```

Now access it in jsp as:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <body>
    <form:form id="yourForm" modelAttribute="yourForm" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td >
            <form:select id="performers" path="performers" title='Select Performers'>
                <option value="">All performers</option>
                <form:options items="${performersList}"/>
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </body>
```

Since performers is already set in controller you will see that performers as auto selected in the jsp.
Similarly you can do it for other dropdown option.

Hope this helps.